# m2e or eclipse ignoring given timestamped snapshot version number of dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

Before I get into this: Yes, I know that I probably shouldn't be using SNAPSHOT dependencies in my production code and Yes, I know that I probably shouldn't be referencing specific timestamped SNAPSHOT versions.

That said, I need to. We're using a framework that is still in its early development and needed to use the SNAPSHOT version to get our product working. However, those working on this framework are clearly in active development and are changing it daily. Given that we need the SNAPSHOT version at a certain time period but do not want any of the new changes, we've specified the specific timestamped SNAPSHOT in our POM dependencies. Now this works fine when I execute from the maven console:

1. delete maven repository (~/.m2/repository)
2. execute maven clean install via command line
3. observe proper timestamp versions being dowloaded into maven repository

However, when I open up eclipse, during its project update, decides to ignore the version number and go ahead and download the latest snapshot version. This is causing many problems and am wondering how I can get eclipse (m2e) to honer the timestamped version number we have provided.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** forgot to mention that I have searched the internet for an answer to this but am not finding any viable answers.

**EDIT:** in addition, i want to avoid hacks. I simply want m2e to honor the timestamp version numbers. I could easily download the specific version number jar myself and install on our nexus repository as a different artifact and reference it via that, but I feel this is a kludge and that m2e should honor the specific version numbers.

**EDIT:** here is a snippet of my pom file as requested. I cannot show the whole thing.

```
...snip...
<!-- Spring - Locked -->
<spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-webmvc.version>2.0.0.BUILD-20140120.130629-28</spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-webmvc.version>
<spring-framework-hateoas.spring-hateoas.version>0.9.0.BUILD-20140122.165601-20</spring-framework-hateoas.spring-hateoas.version>
<spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-core.version>2.0.0.BUILD-20140120.130629-28</spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-core.version>
<spring-framework-data.spring-data-commons.version>1.7.0.BUILD-20140122.170219-75</spring-framework-data.spring-data-commons.version>
...snip...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-webmvc.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework-data.spring-data-rest-core.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework-hateoas.spring-hateoas.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework-data.spring-data-commons.version}</version>
</dependency>
...snip...
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: I cannot attach the whole thing but I've attached where we've identified the dependencies w/ snapshot timestamps

Comment: I guess these are properties? Can you show where they are used in the dependency section?

Comment: updated post with dependecies